# About convert object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object

```
"oldObject": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "path": "http://imageurl",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "path": "http://imageurl"
        }]
```

I want to convert that object to this format.

```
"newObject": [
      {
      img: [
           'http://imageurl form obj 1',
           'http://imageurl form obj 2'
           ]
      name: 'something'
      }
 ]
```

What function should I use to convert and how can I convert that.

Comment: Is this an object with `oldObject` as key or the variable name is `oldObject`?

Comment: where does the "form" comes from and also why having an array with a single object? Please explain your purpose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `path`s since `oldObject` is an array :

```js
const oldObject = [{
    "id": 1,
    "path": "http://imageurl",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "path": "http://imageurl"
  }
]

const newObject = {
  img: oldObject.map(e => e.path),
  name: 'something'
}

console.log(newObject);
```